# Select 1st 2nd and 3rd child element of THIS element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two links that show and hide different divs. The divs have 3 elements h2, p and img and I would like to animate each element separately but can't seem to figure out how.

I would like to click on a link and make each element have a different animation for entrance and leaving. I am pasting my html and jQuery here hope someone can help.

```js
function showonlyone1(thechosenone) {
  $('.uslugetxt').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
      $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
      $(this).children().animate({
        fontSize: "50"
      }, 500)
    } else {
      $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0);
      $(this).children().animate({
        fontSize: "0"
      }, 500)
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebarmenu">
  <a href="javascript:showonlyone1('x1');">analitycs</a>
  <a href="javascript:showonlyone1('x2');">PPC campaigns</a>
</div>
<div class="uslugetxt" id="x1" class="x1">
  <h2 class="naslovx">GOOGLE ANALITYCS</h2>
  <p>
    There is something funny about your data? You double question
  </p>
  <img src="imgs/analitika.jpg" alt="analitika-slika">
</div>

<div class="uslugetxt" id="x2" class="x2">
  <h2 class="naslovx">DISPLAY ADVERTISING</h2>
  <p>
    Display Advertising is partially covered through content Social networks like Facebook, Twitter, MySpace, LikedIn,
  </p>
  <img src="imgs/decasocial.jpg" alt="analitika-slika">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the :nth() pseudo selector?

```js
showonlyone1 = function showonlyone1(thechosenone) {
      $('.uslugetxt').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).fadeTo( "slow", 1 );
               $(this).children(":nth(0)").animate({fontSize: "50"}, 500, function(){ $(this).parent().children(":nth(1)").animate({fontSize: "30"}, 500)
               })
          }
        else {
               $(this).fadeTo( "slow", 0 );
               $(this).children().animate({fontSize: "0"}, 500)
          }
     });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebarmenu">
  <a href="javascript:showonlyone1('x1');">analitycs</a>
  <a href="javascript:showonlyone1('x2');">PPC campaigns</a>
</div>
<div class="uslugetxt" id="x1" class="x1">
  <h2 class="naslovx">GOOGLE ANALITYCS</h2>
  <p>
    There is something funny about your data? You double question
  </p>
  <img src="imgs/analitika.jpg" alt="analitika-slika">
</div>

<div class="uslugetxt" id="x2" class="x2">
  <h2 class="naslovx">DISPLAY ADVERTISING</h2>
  <p>
    Display Advertising is partially covered through content Social networks like Facebook, Twitter, MySpace, LikedIn,
  </p>
  <img src="imgs/decasocial.jpg" alt="analitika-slika">
</div>
```

Now for your next question, how to time animations, simply use the complete function of the animation. So when my first animation completes, the second runs -- but bear in mind that, in the context of the completed function, 'this' refers to the animated element! We'll go back to its parent, select the next child, and animate THAT.

Comment: thank you this works amazingly. Can you please help me with just one more thing. how can i use .delay correctly to time each animation after the other

Comment: You shouldn't use delay(). Instead, the animate() function has a complete callback that happens when the animation is... complete. Place your NEXT animation there.

Comment: @srdjan_susa, Did that help?

Comment: yes it did. but there seems to be a problem that i had before but can't solve. Animation works perfectly after the first click on second link. The first animation is all messy and afterward it all works perfectly.
Do you have any suggestion why is that?

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the calculations for the transform, I'll look into it.